# Ajax Request did not receiving in controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Hello Dears i need to make alot of controllers and alot of search bars for each table i have so i tried to make one ajax code but i think that ajax Request did not response in the controller in the console i have in XHR section the exact url/id?value

also if you have any recommendation about this concept

if i create almoust 20 search bar with each bar the controller in one ajax code is thats right ??!

Thanks in advance

### ```HTML Code

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"  onkeyup='search("{{ url('search/'.@$company->id.'/') }}")' id="search" >
<input type="text" id="from_date" name="from_date">
```

### ```Ajax Code

```
function search(url) {

  var Keyword = $("#search").val()
  var from_date = $("#from_date").val()
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{value:Keyword, from:from_date},
    url:url,
    success:function(rData) {
      $("#content").html(rData.content)
    }
  })
  return false
}
```

### ```Route Code

```
Route::get('search/{id}','ControllerName@search');
```

### ```Controller Code

```
public function search(Request $request, $id)
      {
        $values = $request->value;

        $orders = Orders::where('company_id', $id)->
        where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $values . '%')->get();

        $content = view('ViewPageName' ,compact('orders'))->render();
        return response(['content' => $content]);
      }
```

Comment: Check the network tab of the browser and make sure that the URL is proper: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/imgs/network.png

Comment: the values its appear in XHR sections

Comment: What method you are using for this request GET or POST? check your route and make it proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add  like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}});
```

Or you need pass the csrf-token with key `_token` when post to the controller. This is the documentation for csrf https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: its not posting type the data type is get its just the $request->value show me undefined in the controller when i pass the value with url its working "url:url+value,"

Comment: Oh Sorry man, i not read your type correctly. so i think you should debug the request. can you dd($request) at controller, see the variable sets or not?